# Dropdownmenu Css Background color webkit

Tags: html, css, safari

Im trying to make a dropdown menu with colors, but it wont work in safari. In safari it won't show the colors, its just white

Im now using

```
    background-color:red;
```

Christian

Comment: what exactly do you need? background-color: red; sets the background-color, color: red; sets the font-color. Perhaps you can show us some more code?

Comment: I am tryin to creat a dropdown where you can choose three colors(red,green,yellow). but de colors won't display on ipad and iphone. but they do on the pc

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS declaration should read:

```
background-color:red;
```

Answer (score 0):

May be your html structure is wrong. Or you are applying background color to parent element which contains floating elements as child.